# Repairing a tar.xz file

Tags: tar, data-recovery, xz

I am trying to extract a xz archive, however, around half way through decompression I get the error `Compressed data is corrupt`.

I have tried using xzcat and using the `--ignore-check` flag in case that is the problem, however I run into the same issue.

I have also tried using tar to extract to see if anything would be different, but I get the same results:

```
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt. 
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How would I repair or atleast salvage some data by skipping the corrupted byte(s)?

Comment: Since the data is compressed, your best bet is to try and reobtain it from the source.

Comment: Yep... nothing you can do.  Once a compressed stream is corrupt, there is no way to recover later data since it's meaning depends on all of the previous bytes.